# operator<< in template function: invalid operands

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I have a class `Color`, that has `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Color&)`. It looks like this:

```
struct Color
{
    Color(CID c, sstr s)
    :color(c),
    str(s)
    {
    }


    friend sost& operator<<(sost& o, Color& c)
    {
        o << "\033[1;" << c.color << "m" << c.str << "\033[0m";
        return o;
    }

    CID color;
    sstr str;
};
```

I can call the operator without any issue in all circumstances but in a templated function:

```
template<typename T>
void print_head(const T& head, sost& o)
{
    o << head << "\r";
    o.flush();
    spaces+=(headSize);
}
```

I invoke it with `print_head<helper::Color>(rsym, o);` with `rsym` being a instance of `Color`. And I get

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('sost'
  (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const helper::Color')
            o << head << "\r";
            ~ ^  ~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization
  'blk::Bouncer::print_head<helper::Color>' requested here
                            print_head<helper::Color>(rsym, o);
```

Whats wrong with the template function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator takes a non const reference but `head` is const.

You should change it to

```
friend sost& operator<<(sost& o, const Color& c)
```

Comment: Thanks! Stupid me... But can you tell me where and if I could actually have seen this in the error message?

Comment: The error message gets you part way to the problem: "invalid operands" indicates something doesn't match between the parameters you're passing vs what the function takes. From there you have to look at the situation yourself. From experience, the problem is usually not with the stream parameter. And then seeing `const helper::Color` hints at the idea "Is there some reason a const parameter wouldn't be accepted?"